# Is the speed the same when the chip is the same?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

If two Macs use the same chip the compute speed should be the same correct? What would the difference in speed be between:

- [2022 Apple MacBook Air](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B3C5H787) Laptop with M2 chip
- [2022 Apple MacBook Pro](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B3C57XLR) Laptop with M2 chip

Both have M2. But the other parts like the bus, the memory and the SSD may be different.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference is active cooling in the MacBook Pro. For any workloads that last longer than 5-10 minutes, expect a slight performance increase in the Pro relative to the Air.

This does NOT mean the Air cannot handle sustained load. It will just be slower than the Pro while doing so. For example, I find it can sustain Minecraft performance at 60 FPS without any trouble, even after it starts thermal throttling.

One note on SSDs: some models (M2 Air/Pro 256GB models specifically) use a single 256GB chip inside, rather than two 128GB chips. This will make them slower than the 512GB models that use two 256GB chips. However, for your comparison, the same spec will be the same so this shouldn't be a concern.